# How to get the previous and next sibling id with javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

What i'm trying to do is that, i'm using arrow keys to set focus to next/previous tabs.
i'm using javascript `.focus()` method to set the focus on to the element using the ID.

i'm getting the active tab id, but i need to get the previous and next tab ids' so that i can set focus.
but i'm not able to get the previous and next tab id's

i'm getting `Cannot read property 'id' of null` error when i tried.

here is what i have tried.

initEvents: function(){
    this.callParent(arguments);

```
var keyNav = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: this.el,
    binding: [{
            key: Ext.EventObject.LEFT,
            fn: this.handleKeys.bind(this)
        }, {
            key: Ext.EventObject.RIGHT,
            fn: this.handleKeys.bind(this)
        }
    ],
    scope: this
});
```

},

```
handleKeys: function(keyCode, event) {
    var currentElement = event.getTarget(), targetEl = Ext.get(event.getTarget()),currentElementId = event.getTarget().id, nextElement = document.getElementById(currentElementId).nextElementSibling.id,previousElement = document.getElementById(currentElementId).previousElementSibling.id;
    if (event.keyCode === Ext.EventObject.LEFT)
    {
        getElementById(previousElement).focus();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === Ext.EventObject.RIGHT){
        getElementById(nextElement).focus()
    }
},
```

Example of tabs [here](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/4.2.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, this works

```
elem.previousSibling
elem.nextSibling
```